# Laravel best place to control your roles and permissions

Tags: laravel

I am starting with spatie/laravel-permission. I can use the permission into my blade. Works fine. What i want is to control it at a higher level. So i don't have to use it in every create.blade.php

```
@can('add users') or @hasrole('administrator')
```

Where and how can i achieve that?

Comment: Laravel 5.5 will have Blade::if declarations so you can make custom if directives https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-5/episodes/10

Comment: Did you consider routes and middleware as an option?
Also there is an laracasts lesson regarding authentication and authorization

Comment: Yes @Maky, now i have $request->user()->can(\Request::route()->getName()) in a middleware. So in my permission table i have users.create, etc for a specific user. Is this the "good" way?

Comment: it states in the documentation of the plugin:
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin,access_backend']], function () {
    Route::get('someroute','somecontroller@method');
});
this is just to give you an idea. The thing you placed seems messy IMHO

Comment: @Maky saw that, but thats is not where i am looking for. I want to check dynamicly if a user is logged in with a specific role and/or permission. So why messy IMHO!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is a middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role, $permission=null)
{
    if(Auth::user()){
        if($request->user()->can(\Request::route()->getName())===false){
            return response(view('noaccess'));
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

[image: user has permission table]

[image: persmissions table]